# Converting stream json files into parquet format in S3

Tags: pyspark, parquet

Kinesis Firehose continuously stream json files to S3 bucket. Using pyspark I need to convert into parquet and write to another bucket. Plannig to run this EMR job once in every 30 mins. I used the following code, but EMR job is running long(more than 4 hours and then i killed the job) to convert small files(Around 400K small files and total size is around 30GB). 
Can someone give your input to increase the performance of the job?

Code:

```
# Loop through all folders
for k in sourceBucket.list():
    source = k.bucket.name + '/' + k.key
    srcsubfolder = source.split('/')
    if srcsubfolder[2] != '':
        sourcePath = 's3://' + k.bucket.name + '/' + k.key

        # derive target path
        removefilenamefromkey = k.key.split('/')[:-1]
        targetPath = 's3://' + targetBucket.name +'/' + '/'.join(removefilenamefromkey)

        #Covert Json into Parquet files
        dfjson = spark.read.json(sourcePath)
        dfjsoncollower = dfjson.toDF(*[x.lower() for x in dfjson.columns])
        dfjsoncollower.write.mode("append").parquet(targetPath)
```

Comment: What's the size of your EMR cluster?  How much RAM does each node have?  In my experience, I've had jobs run for way too long when my cluster/nodes aren't big enough

Comment: Hi Bob, Thanks for your reply. I am running this on one master and two core with following configuration.m4.xlarge
8 vCPU, 16 GiB memory, EBS only storage
EBS Storage:32 GiB

Comment: I would try adding 2 more nodes.  Since your data is 30 GB, and your cluster only has 32 GB of RAM, it's a pretty tight fit.  With one master and 4 nodes, you'd have 64 GB RAM in the nodes.

Comment: any luck getting this to run faster??

Comment: I added two more nodes but still its taking longer. Looks like i need to modify my script. currently its reading one file each time and converting It into parquet. I might have to read bulk files and convert them into parquet.

Comment: @user9059951 did you managed to rewrite your script to get a better performance? Actually, I have the same error, plus, my parquet files are somewhat only 6kb, even tho the smallest JSON file is 1mb with many records inside. Any ideas what may be the cause? Can you share your script and example JSON data file with multiple records? That would be super helpful, I've spent some weeks on this thing now.. :(